# What is the most appropriate way to compare a string to a stringable object by value?

Tags: c#, reference, refactoring, resharper, windows-store-apps

With this:

```
if (args.Parameter == "ContactIntermediaryPage")
```

...in a NavigatedTo() event handler, Resharper tells me: "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the left hand side to type 'string'"

So should I change it to one of the following, and, if so, which one:

```
if ((string)args.Parameter == "ContactIntermediaryPage")

if (args.Parameter.ToString() == "ContactIntermediaryPage")

if (args.Parameter.Equals("ContactIntermediaryPage"))
```

Comment: Is there any concern for the `null` case where `args.Parameter` is null? That can _definitely_ have a significant impact depending on which option you use.

Comment: `if (args.Parameter.Equals("ContactIntermediaryPage"))` would not work - since it expects an object of type `Parameter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first one if args.Parameter is always a string. It saves an extra call.

otherwise the second one if, and only if, all possible strings are within your code. If so, I would define the strings as constants and reference them in one place if possible.

If neither of the above are true, then go for Tigran's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would choose third one, making it also case *insensitive* (if this is suitable in your case)

```
if (args.Parameter.ToString().Equals(
               "ContactIntermediaryPage", 
                StringComparsion.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

In other words, if you're comparing to a `string` make *left* part of equation a `string`, to make clear to a compiler and to a reader of your code, what you're going to do on that line.

Comment: Prb stating the obvious, but just to add that you don't need the `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` if you do care about case (it's always going to be in CamelCase.